# Proof of probability exercise

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

Consider the following problem:

> Let $X,Y$ be random variables with values in $[0,+\infty)$ and $V$ a random variable with values in $(0,+\infty)$. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent from $V$ and that $\phi_{\log V}$ (characteristic function of $\log V$) has isolated zeroes. Then
>
> 1. If $X \neq 0$ a.c. and $Y \neq 0$ a.c. and $XV$ and $YV$ have the same distribution, prove that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution
> 2. Prove point 1. without the hypotesis of $X \neq 0$ a.c. and $Y \neq 0$ a.c.

Point 1. follows from properties of the characteristic function and it is clear to me. The problem is the proof of point 2. that is stated as follows:

*Observe that $P(X=0)=P(XV=0)=P(YV=0)=P(Y=0)$ and that, given a borel set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we have that $$P(X \in A)=P(X \in A \mid X \neq 0)P(X \neq 0) +\mathbf{1}_{\{0 \in A\}}P(X=0)$$ and similarly for $Y$, so it is enough to prove that $$P(X \in A \mid X \neq 0)=P(Y \in A \mid Y \neq 0)$$ but this follows immediately from point 1. **since under $P(\cdot \mid X \neq 0)$ we have that $X \neq 0$ a.c. and similarly for $Y$.***

I really don't understand how the bolded part should imply the thesis: the first thing that is not clear to me is that changing the probability on the space that we have (switching from $P$ to $P(\cdot \mid X \neq 0)$) can change also the distribution of the variables, and so the hypothesis that we have could not be more valid (in particular $\phi_{\log V}$ can be different), but this doesn't bother me much since I suppose that we are taking for granted that the distributions of the variables remain untouched.

What I really don't understand is that $X \neq 0$ and $Y \neq 0$ a.c. under two different probabilities, so how can we apply the first point since they have to be nonzero a.c. at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisit the proof of 1, you'll notice you don't actually need for $X$ and $Y$ to be on the same probability space if you consider $V_{1},V_{2} \sim V$, $V_{1}X \sim V_{2}Y$ , $V_{1}$ independent of $X$ and $V_{2}$ independent of $Y$.

By independence, $V$ w.r.t. $P(.|X \neq 0)$ and $P(.|Y \neq 0)$ are distributed as $V$ w.r.t. $P$.
Also, because $\{XV \neq 0 \} = \{X \neq 0\}$ and $\{YV \neq 0 \} = \{Y \neq 0\}$ you can easily show by definition of conditional probability that $XV$ w.r.t. $P(.|X \neq 0)$ $\sim$ $YV$ w.r.t. $P(.|Y \neq 0)$. Hence you are in the conditions of 1.